# Product variation error on cart page, not showing buttons, price or quantity

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I have a big issue right now on my Wordpress site. Simple products do work just fine, but when I add product variations in attribute, and add that product, cart page just bugs out. After the description nothing is loaded, don't have the price, quantity, even footer doesn't load, as it stops loading there.

I tried overriding Woocommerce files with theme woocommerce files, but with no luck. I searched everything and everywhere for solution, but there is none. I tried everything with Product variations, but with no luck also.

The website is: https://ticketshoprd.com

Also, mini-cart in the menu is working just fine with product variations.

The event which is with variations is the Boat Party one.

Code from cart.php

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

wc_print_notices();

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>

<form action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

<table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
            <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Evento', 'startit' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Precio', 'startit' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Cantidad', 'startit' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-subtotal"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'startit' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

        <?php
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">

                    <td class="product-remove">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'startit' ),
                                esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                            ), $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                        <?php
                            $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                echo qode_startit_kses_img($thumbnail);
                            } else {
                                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail );
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php _e( 'Product', 'startit' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;';
                            } else {
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_title() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                            }

                            // Meta data
                            echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item );

                            // Backorder notification
                            if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                                echo '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'startit' ) . '</p>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php _e( 'Price', 'startit' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php _e( 'Quantity', 'startit' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                            } else {
                                $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                    'input_name'  => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                    'input_value' => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                    'max_value'   => $_product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $_product->get_stock_quantity(),
                                    'min_value'   => '0'
                                ), $_product, false );
                            }

                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
                        ?>
                    </td>

                    <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php _e( 'Total', 'startit' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' );
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                    <div class="coupon">

                        <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon', 'startit' ); ?>:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Código del cupón', 'startit' ); ?>" />

                        <?php
                            //Override Apply Coupon Button
                            do_action('qode_startit_woocommerce_apply_coupon_button');
                        ?>

                        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class="qodef-cart-proceed-update">


                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>

<input type="submit" class="qodef-btn qodef-btn-medium qodef-btn-default checkout-button alt wc-forward" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Actualizar Carrito', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />


                    <?php
                        //Override Apply Coupon Button
                        do_action('qode_startit_woocommerce_update_cart_button');
                    ?>

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>

                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>

</form>

<div class="cart-collaterals">

    <?php if ( is_cart() ) : ?>
        <div class="qodef-shipping-calculator">
            <?php woocommerce_shipping_calculator(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="qodef-cart-totals">

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' ); ?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bugs out?" Please be more specific about your errors and show your code.

Comment: @Difster As I said, it does not show anything except name of the event and id, as You can see on the website I posted. You can't do anything, it just fails to load everything after the name of the event. Everything is working correctly on single product, checkout buttons, price etc. I will edit this post with the code from cart.php

Comment: That's a lot of code to slog through and nothing stands out. Have you turned on error reporting in WP to see if it reports a problem?

Comment: @Difser I checked the code in details, nothing stand out to me either. I have, no errors. Just this JS error: GET https://ticketshoprd.com/cart/ 500 ()